# useGlobalPipes не работает, если определено useGlobalFilters nestJS

Tags: filter, nestjs, pipes

Столкнулся с тем, что мой кастомный Pipe класс не отрабатывает, если вместе с ним глобально определен кастомный фильтр. Если убираю кастомный фильтр, то Pipe отрабатывает как надо. Подскажите, в чем проблема? Спасибо. К слову, код тестовый, но рабочий.

```
app.useGlobalFilters(new NotFoundException())
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe())

@Catch(HttpException)
export class NotFoundException implements ExceptionFilter {
    catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
        const ctx = host.switchToHttp()
        const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>()
        const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>()
        const status = exception.getStatus()
        
        response.status(status)
        .json([{
            statusCode: status,
            property: null,
            message: ''
        }])
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class ValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
    async transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
        const obj = plainToClass(metadata.metatype, value)
        const errors = await validate(obj)

        const errorsArr: string = []
        if (errors.length) {
            errors.map(err => {                
                if (!err.children.length) {
                    Object.values(err.constraints).map((error: string) => {     
                        errorsArr.push(error)
                    })
                }
            })
            
            throw new ValidationException(uniqWith(errorsArr, isEqual))
        }

        return value
    }
}
```

Пробовал переделать глобальное определение в провайдерский модуль. Пробовал определение на уровне контроллера, а не глобально. И все безуспешно.